# Consulta com duas tabelas

Tags: php, sql, query

Estou em um projeto, tenho a tabela cliente e trabalho. 
Um trabalho tem um cliente. Já relacionei as tabelas, mas preciso fazer um select que a partir do id do cliente na tabela trabalho, retorne o nome do cliente.

Tenho que fazer uma consulta para exibir no meu código em php.

Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

Answer (score 2):

Supondo que suas tabelas sejam assim:

CLIENTE
    id int,
    nome_cliente VARCHAR

TRABALHO 
    id int
    id_cliente int
    descr_trabalho VARCHAR

Você poderia fazer assim:

```
SELECT a.id, a.descr_trabalho, b.nome_cliente from TRABALHO a 
    left join CLIENTE b on
       a.id_cliente = b.id
```